# How do you make a change to one array, based on another array, otherwise add to the end of the the first array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have 2 arrays of data. I want to be able to "loop" through the first array, adding each item to a new "final array" in the same order, but for each item it checks, if it has the same ID as one of the items from a second array, then I want it to NOT add that item from the first array to the final array, but instead want it to add that matching ID item from the second array instead in its place.

If there are no items from the first array that match the item from the second array, that second array item will instead get added to the bottom of the final array.

Example:

```js
// array 1
  const mainArray = [
    {name: 'example1', id: 1}, 
    {name: 'example2', id: 2}, 
    {name: 'example3', id: 3}, 
    {name: 'example4', id: 4}, 
    {name: 'example5', id: 5},
  ]
  // array 2
  const uploadArray = [
    {name: 'floop', id: 2}, 
    {name: 'example10', id: 10}
  ]
// adds all items from mainArray to finalArray, but since floop also had an id of 2, 
//it got added in place of example2, since example10 didn't match any items in mainArray, 
// it was added to finalArray after all of mainArray was added to finalArray
  finalArray = [
    {name: 'example1', id: 1}, 
    {name: 'floop', id: 2}, 
    {name: 'example3', id: 3}, 
    {name: 'example4', id: 4}, 
    {name: 'example5', id: 5},
    {name: 'example10', id: 10}
  ]
```

Comment: What conditional have you tried to add to make this work? Have you attempted any code to achieve your goal array? Please include that code along with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Array.map`, you can update the first array based on the second array and after that, get the output by binding two arrays (updated first array and second array).

```js
const mainArray = [
  {
    name: 'example1',
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'example2',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'example3',
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'example4',
    id: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'example5',
    id: 5
  },
]

const uploadArray = [
  {
    name: 'floop',
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'example10',
    id: 10
  }
];

const replacedMainArray = mainArray.map(item => {
  const existed = uploadArray.findIndex(({ id }) => item.id === id);
  if (existed >= 0) {
    const updatedItem = { ...uploadArray[existed] };
    uploadArray.splice(existed, 1);
    return updatedItem;
  }
  return item;
});

const result = [ ...replacedMainArray, ...uploadArray ];
console.log(result);
```

Comment: This does work with the example provided, but what about objects with a variable amount of properties? Would it still be able to completely replace the object?

Comment: For the same id, you want to replace the second item with first item? (all keys)

Comment: If the ids are the same the matching id object in the second array will replace the matching id object in the first array entirely. I just used name and and id for example but it would have more properties in each object than just id and name.

Comment: I have updated my answer. @J64 Check `Array.map` callback. `const updatedItem = { ...uploadArray[existed] }` will work.

Comment: Seems to work in the appropriate way from what I can tell.

Comment: Can you approve my answer if it works as expected? @J64